# Persist value in React Select Creatable

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using the Creatable of React.Select, and I want to persist to the backend whenever a new option is created, so right now I have this:

`onChange = (value) => {
 if(!valueExists(value)) {
   //Call persist endpoint
 }
}`

What I don't like about this approach is that by default, Creatable, adds the option even before I have persisted. I can't find a way to control that. Ideally I would just add the option once I have persisted in the backend. Is there a way for ReactSelect.Creatable to let you know once a value is asked to be created?

Comment: did you add your onChange handler to onNewOptionClick prop?

Comment: Nops. I didn't know about that option.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. That works!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Mukesh, the problem is that the function doesn't allow you to change how it is inserted in the options. That is, if I want to change how the value or label looks. Do you know how to change that?

Comment: I have not used react-select :). I found that option for you by reading the source code here - https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Creatable.js#L19